# Open links from non-native app in Safari app

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

We are creating a non-native iPhone app that will eventually go through the phonegap process. But what I'm trying to do right now is: We have links that open in Twitter and LinkedIn, but when clicking them they open right in the same app window. Is there any way to force the links to open in the actual Safari app. It looks like this is possible with Objective-C, but I don't see how to do it with HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy one of the url's you're trying into your question so we can see the format you are using?

Answer (score 0):

http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/15/open-external-links-in-safariapp/

Comment: Does it have to be in phonegap to do this? Another company is actually implementing the phonegap portion of the project, so if that's the case I will have to let them know to do this. Sorry, I don't have experience with phonegap personally, so all I know is vaguely what it does. Thanks for the resource!